# Creating a class for an object

Tags: java, class, object, parameters, double

I'm creating a class that will create a Pizza object. It takes into account its size (diameter in inches), the number of slices, the cost of the pie, and the type of pizza.

This is my first time doing such a thing, so I've run into some snafus.

Here is the code for the class Pizza:

```
    class Pizza
{

    //instance variables
    int size;
    int slices;
    int pieCost;
    String typeOfPizza;


    //constructors
    Pizza (String typeOfPizza)
    {
        System.out.println (typeOfPizza);
    }

    Pizza ()
    {
        System.out.println ("pizza");
    }

    Pizza (int s, int sl, int c)
    {
        size = s;
        slices = sl;
        pieCost = c;
        typeOfPizza = "????";
    }

    Pizza (String name, int s, int sl, int c)
    {
        typeOfPizza = name;
        size = s;
        slices = sl;
        pieCost = c;
    }

    //behavior

    double areaPerSlice(int size, int slices)
    {
        double wholeArea = Math.PI * Math.pow ((size/2), 2);
        double sliceArea = wholeArea/slices;
        return sliceArea;
    }

    double costPerSlice (double pieCost, int slices)
    {
        double sliceCost = pieCost/slices; 
        return sliceCost;
    }

    double costPerSquareInch (double sliceCost, double sliceArea)
    {
        double costPerSquareInch = sliceCost/sliceArea;
    }

    String getName(String name)
    {
        String typeOfPizza = name;
        return typeOfPizza;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the main method that calls on the Pizza class:

```
class PizzaTest
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String typeOfPizza = "Cheese";
        int size = 10;                  //in inches, referring to the diameter of the pizza
        int numberOfSlices = 10;            //number of slices
        int costOfPie = 20;

        Pizza myPizza = new Pizza (typeOfPizza, size, numberOfSlices, costOfPie);

        System.out.printf ("Your %s pizza has %.2f square inches per slice.\n", myPizza.getName(),
                   myPizza.areaPerSlice() );

        System.out.printf ("One slice costs $%.2f, which comes to $%.3f per square inch.\n", 
                   myPizza.costPerSlice(), myPizza.costPerSquareInch());
    }
}
```

Essentially, the output should print the following:

Your Pepperoni pizza has 20.11 square inches per slice.
One slice costs $1.05, which comes to $0.052 per square inch.

The values can be ignored, they're from an example with different parameters. When I go to compile this program, I get the following errors:

```
getName(java.lang.String) in Pizza cannot be applied to ()
        System.out.printf ("Your %s pizza has %.2f square inches per slice.\n", myPizza.getName(),
                                                                                       ^
PizzaTest.java:20: areaPerSlice(int,int) in Pizza cannot be applied to ()
                   myPizza.areaPerSlice() );
                          ^
PizzaTest.java:23: costPerSlice(double,int) in Pizza cannot be applied to ()
                   myPizza.costPerSlice(), myPizza.costPerSquareInch());
                          ^
PizzaTest.java:23: costPerSquareInch(double,double) in Pizza cannot be applied to ()
                   myPizza.costPerSlice(), myPizza.costPerSquareInch());
```

Any input as to how I can fix this? Thanks for helping out a beginning programmer!

Comment: are both class i.e `Pizza` and `PizzaTest` in the same package?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
String getName(String name)
{
    String typeOfPizza = name;
    return typeOfPizza;
}
```

to

```
String getName()
{
    return typeOfPizza;
}
```

and

```
double costPerSquareInch (double sliceCost, double sliceArea){
    double costPerSquareInch = sliceCost/sliceArea;
}
```

to

```
double costPerSquareInch (double sliceCost, double sliceArea){
    return costPerSquareInch = sliceCost/sliceArea;
}
```

and

```
    System.out.printf ("Your %s pizza has %.2f square inches per slice.\n", myPizza.getName(),
               myPizza.areaPerSlice() );

    System.out.printf ("One slice costs $%.2f, which comes to $%.3f per square inch.\n", 
               myPizza.costPerSlice(costOfPie,numberOfSlices), myPizza.costPerSquareInch(sliceCost,sliceArea));
```

to

```
    System.out.printf ("Your %s pizza has %.2f square inches per slice.\n", myPizza.getName(),
               myPizza.areaPerSlice(size, numberOfSlices) );

    System.out.printf ("One slice costs $%.2f, which comes to $%.3f per square inch.\n", 
               myPizza.costPerSlice(costOfPie,numberOfSlices), myPizza.costPerSquareInch(sliceCost,sliceArea));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes a non optional string.

```
String getName(String name)
{
    String typeOfPizza = name;
    return typeOfPizza;
}
```

Should be two functions

```
String getName() { // needed a string before.
  return typeOfPizza;
}

void setName(String name) {
  typeOfPizza = name;
}
```

Also, you should probably call that field `name` or those method(s) should be `getTypeOfPizza` and `setTypeOfPizza`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `Pizza` class will compile.

```
 double costPerSquareInch (double sliceCost, double sliceArea){
    double costPerSquareInch = sliceCost/sliceArea;
    // missing return.
}
```

First make that one correct.

Then

```
myPizza.getName() // need input argument as String
```

Then this should as

```
myPizza.getName("inputString");
```

Also other two has same input argument issues.

```
 myPizza.areaPerSlice()// two int input arguments.
```

Corrected as

```
 myPizza.areaPerSlice(1,2);
```

Next one

```
 myPizza.costPerSlice();// double and int input arguments.
```

correct as

```
myPizza.costPerSlice(2.0,2);
```

Finally

```
myPizza.costPerSquareInch() // two double input arguments.
```

Corrected as

```
myPizza.costPerSquareInch(2.0,1.0) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

the errors say it all...

```
double areaPerSlice(int size, int slices)
    {
        double wholeArea = Math.PI * Math.pow ((size/2), 2);
        double sliceArea = wholeArea/slices;
        return sliceArea;
    }

System.out.printf ("Your %s pizza has %.2f square inches per slice.\n", myPizza.getName(),
           myPizza.areaPerSlice() );
```

in the method definition, you are taking 2 args... but while calling you are using 0 arguments... THIS APPLIES FOR OTHER ERRORS ALSO.

Answer (score 0):

```
problem
```

Your function is asking for a parameter.As you don't have function `getName` with `single parameter`

```
Solution
```

You have to define a method like

```
String getName( )
{
    return typeOfPizza;
}
```

Same you have to do for these calls also.

```
myPizza.areaPerSlice()
myPizza.costPerSlice()
myPizza.costPerSquareInch()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Pizza
{

//instance variables
pirvate int size;
private int slices;
private int pieCost;
private String typeOfPizza;


//constructors
public Pizza (String typeOfPizza)
{
    System.out.println (typeOfPizza);
}

public Pizza ()
{
    System.out.println ("pizza");
}

public Pizza (int size, int slices, int pieCost)
{
    this.size = size;
    this.slices = slices;
    this.pieCost = pieCost;
    typeOfPizza = "????";
}

public Pizza (String typeOfPizza, int size, int slices, int pieCost)
{
    this.typeOfPizza = typeOfPizza
    this.size = size;
    this.slices = slices;
    this.pieCost = pieCost;
}

//behavior

public double areaPerSlice(int size, int slices)
{
    double wholeArea = Math.PI * Math.pow ((size/2), 2);
    double sliceArea = wholeArea/slices;
    return sliceArea;
}

public double costPerSlice (double pieCost, int slices)
{
    double sliceCost = pieCost/slices; 
    return sliceCost;
}

public double costPerSquareInch (double sliceCost, double sliceArea)
{
    double costPerSquareInch = sliceCost/sliceArea;
}

public String getName(String name)
{
    String typeOfPizza = name;
    return typeOfPizza;
}
}


class PizzaTest
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    String typeOfPizza = "Cheese";
    int size = 10;                  //in inches, referring to the diameter of the pizza
    int numberOfSlices = 10;            //number of slices
    int costOfPie = 20;

    Pizza myPizza = new Pizza (typeOfPizza, size, numberOfSlices, costOfPie);

    System.Out.Printf ("Your"+myPizza.getName()+" pizza has "+myPizza.areaPerSlice() +".2f square inches per slice.\n");

    System.Out.Printf ("One slice costs "+myPizza.costPerSlice()+".2f, which comes to "+myPizza.costPerSquareInch()+".3f per square inch.\n");
}
}
```

Hope this will help you.